# Find NULLable columns that could be NON NULL

Tags: mysql

I'm struggling with a database that has poor hygiene in regards to NON NULL columns.

Some columns always have data, i.e. they could be NON NULL, but they aren't.
Others surprise me when I expect them to always have data but they don't, and I trigger null pointer exceptions.

I'd like to know which columns have no NULL entries in them, i.e. that could be NON NULL, but that aren't. Right now I know I can do this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(column) FROM table WHERE column IS NULL
```

But ideally I wouldn't have to do this column-by-column, table-by-table. Is there a way to automate this?

Answer (score 1):

You do need to do it table by table.

But you can query like this to count the instances of NULL:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS total_rows,
  SUM(column1 IS NULL) AS column1_nulls,
  SUM(column2 IS NULL) AS column2_nulls,
  SUM(column3 IS NULL) AS column3_nulls,
  ...for all the columns...
FROM mytable;
```

In MySQL, boolean expressions evaluate to the integers 1 or 0. So the SUM() of 1's and 0's is equivalent to the COUNT() where the boolean expression is true. This trick allows you to count multiple things on all rows, without using WHERE conditions.

Comment: Thanks. Kind of a pain but if there are no better answers this'll have to do.